# CSS scrollbar autohide not working after webkit customization

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

The default behavior on Chrome for scrollbars is to be hidden until they are used. On safari, they are hidden all the time. After adding these custom styles, specifically the width attribute, both browsers always show the scrollbar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #d1d5db;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Is there any way to style the scrollbar without overriding the default hiding behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you are customising the scroll bars for a particular `<div>`, you can adjust the `overflow` and `padding-right` properties on `:hover` to make a customised scrollbar behave similiarly to a default one. This trick doesn’t really work on the main page scrollbar, though, because a `:hover` style on the body will be active whenever the cursor is within the page.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.d1 {
  background: lime;
  overflow: auto;
}

.d2 {
  background: cyan;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: calc(1em + 4px);
}

.d2:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.d2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}

.d2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

div>p:first-child {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
<p>
Default scrollbar
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id massa blandit, commodo risus id, tempor orci. Pellentesque libero diam, blandit et blandit et, ultricies eu nisi. Fusce sed elit at turpis imperdiet auctor. Aenean iaculis nulla non sodales eleifend. Maecenas ullamcorper ut justo vel sollicitudin. Fusce sit amet viverra quam. Vestibulum fringilla nibh libero. Cras ultricies ante sed libero feugiat tempus.
</p>
<p>
Donec ac erat tempus, volutpat dui quis, venenatis mauris. Curabitur suscipit urna ut neque consequat elementum. Aenean eget libero viverra, pulvinar mauris id, fringilla metus. Nullam porta arcu id dolor venenatis faucibus. Nullam commodo fringilla turpis eu porta. Quisque a lacus dictum, pharetra lectus in, mollis turpis. Duis pharetra, diam non sodales ultricies, turpis quam maximus sapien, sit amet sollicitudin dui tortor vitae quam.
</p>
<p>
Phasellus ipsum arcu, vestibulum eu hendrerit at, euismod sed libero. Nunc leo enim, efficitur id commodo quis, placerat quis diam. Praesent sapien ligula, rutrum non neque nec, consectetur pellentesque velit. Donec lacinia viverra arcu, in lacinia lorem suscipit et. Nunc interdum non est id sagittis. Fusce gravida scelerisque purus, ultricies tempor magna elementum vel. Nunc vitae quam vitae nisl venenatis posuere vel in metus. Nulla mattis eros pellentesque metus pharetra fringilla. Aliquam sit amet quam mollis lectus finibus blandit. Aliquam molestie nibh eget diam faucibus tempus. Sed laoreet, quam eget tempor rhoncus, lacus diam condimentum odio, at cursus magna massa eget metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed sollicitudin pellentesque accumsan. In lacinia tempus est, et pellentesque eros dapibus sit amet. Donec sed posuere ipsum. Sed aliquet placerat odio ut iaculis.
</p>
<p>
Nullam sollicitudin finibus neque sed convallis. Proin quis sollicitudin mauris. Etiam lacinia vehicula nunc lacinia pulvinar. Phasellus blandit, mauris eget efficitur feugiat, ex mi tincidunt justo, vitae luctus turpis nisi sagittis nibh. Pellentesque nec congue nulla, ut feugiat ex. Etiam sollicitudin, arcu sed blandit accumsan, ex tortor feugiat mauris, vitae eleifend ante arcu vel justo. Maecenas eget fringilla risus. Pellentesque in malesuada mauris, non laoreet nisi. Aliquam facilisis lacus et ante egestas, sit amet aliquet diam feugiat. Pellentesque molestie elit ex, nec cursus est molestie eget. Etiam iaculis orci ut ex efficitur, varius lacinia leo molestie. Nullam at tincidunt velit. Fusce id sem et ante pharetra convallis a eget dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec iaculis pulvinar ipsum et condimentum. Suspendisse sollicitudin justo nisl, a egestas elit feugiat vitae.
</p>
<p>
Aliquam sodales, metus et dignissim volutpat, ex ante dignissim felis, vitae viverra risus ligula id risus. Cras eget posuere nibh, ut vestibulum elit. Nunc molestie et urna sit amet facilisis. Duis ultricies quis dolor eu luctus. Nunc ut hendrerit nunc. Maecenas a nunc consequat, posuere ligula nec, hendrerit libero. Curabitur volutpat risus est, non eleifend felis dictum sit amet. In leo nunc, semper eget aliquam et, dignissim sed elit. Nam viverra velit non quam faucibus, gravida tincidunt massa volutpat. Ut in faucibus tortor, vel dapibus turpis. Nulla eu sodales enim. Fusce eu ipsum non enim tristique venenatis. Nulla molestie interdum leo a tincidunt. Nullam et lacus quis neque tincidunt laoreet porttitor vitae arcu. Nullam dolor ex, dignissim in risus sit amet, interdum vestibulum ligula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
</div>

<div class="d2">
<p>
Custom scrollbar
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id massa blandit, commodo risus id, tempor orci. Pellentesque libero diam, blandit et blandit et, ultricies eu nisi. Fusce sed elit at turpis imperdiet auctor. Aenean iaculis nulla non sodales eleifend. Maecenas ullamcorper ut justo vel sollicitudin. Fusce sit amet viverra quam. Vestibulum fringilla nibh libero. Cras ultricies ante sed libero feugiat tempus.
</p>
<p>
Donec ac erat tempus, volutpat dui quis, venenatis mauris. Curabitur suscipit urna ut neque consequat elementum. Aenean eget libero viverra, pulvinar mauris id, fringilla metus. Nullam porta arcu id dolor venenatis faucibus. Nullam commodo fringilla turpis eu porta. Quisque a lacus dictum, pharetra lectus in, mollis turpis. Duis pharetra, diam non sodales ultricies, turpis quam maximus sapien, sit amet sollicitudin dui tortor vitae quam.
</p>
<p>
Phasellus ipsum arcu, vestibulum eu hendrerit at, euismod sed libero. Nunc leo enim, efficitur id commodo quis, placerat quis diam. Praesent sapien ligula, rutrum non neque nec, consectetur pellentesque velit. Donec lacinia viverra arcu, in lacinia lorem suscipit et. Nunc interdum non est id sagittis. Fusce gravida scelerisque purus, ultricies tempor magna elementum vel. Nunc vitae quam vitae nisl venenatis posuere vel in metus. Nulla mattis eros pellentesque metus pharetra fringilla. Aliquam sit amet quam mollis lectus finibus blandit. Aliquam molestie nibh eget diam faucibus tempus. Sed laoreet, quam eget tempor rhoncus, lacus diam condimentum odio, at cursus magna massa eget metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed sollicitudin pellentesque accumsan. In lacinia tempus est, et pellentesque eros dapibus sit amet. Donec sed posuere ipsum. Sed aliquet placerat odio ut iaculis.
</p>
<p>
Nullam sollicitudin finibus neque sed convallis. Proin quis sollicitudin mauris. Etiam lacinia vehicula nunc lacinia pulvinar. Phasellus blandit, mauris eget efficitur feugiat, ex mi tincidunt justo, vitae luctus turpis nisi sagittis nibh. Pellentesque nec congue nulla, ut feugiat ex. Etiam sollicitudin, arcu sed blandit accumsan, ex tortor feugiat mauris, vitae eleifend ante arcu vel justo. Maecenas eget fringilla risus. Pellentesque in malesuada mauris, non laoreet nisi. Aliquam facilisis lacus et ante egestas, sit amet aliquet diam feugiat. Pellentesque molestie elit ex, nec cursus est molestie eget. Etiam iaculis orci ut ex efficitur, varius lacinia leo molestie. Nullam at tincidunt velit. Fusce id sem et ante pharetra convallis a eget dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec iaculis pulvinar ipsum et condimentum. Suspendisse sollicitudin justo nisl, a egestas elit feugiat vitae.
</p>
<p>
Aliquam sodales, metus et dignissim volutpat, ex ante dignissim felis, vitae viverra risus ligula id risus. Cras eget posuere nibh, ut vestibulum elit. Nunc molestie et urna sit amet facilisis. Duis ultricies quis dolor eu luctus. Nunc ut hendrerit nunc. Maecenas a nunc consequat, posuere ligula nec, hendrerit libero. Curabitur volutpat risus est, non eleifend felis dictum sit amet. In leo nunc, semper eget aliquam et, dignissim sed elit. Nam viverra velit non quam faucibus, gravida tincidunt massa volutpat. Ut in faucibus tortor, vel dapibus turpis. Nulla eu sodales enim. Fusce eu ipsum non enim tristique venenatis. Nulla molestie interdum leo a tincidunt. Nullam et lacus quis neque tincidunt laoreet porttitor vitae arcu. Nullam dolor ex, dignissim in risus sit amet, interdum vestibulum ligula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
</div>
```

Is it really worth the effort to customise the scroll bar? I’ve never come across a situation where I judged the benefits would outweigh the drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I guess whether it's worth it is a matter of priorities. Unfortunately, the behavior is not really a hover, since, chrome waits til you initiate a scroll with a mouse or trackpad to show the bar, and I don't really want to force all browsers to behave the same way. Ideally, I'm looking for a way to get out of the way of the default behavior, not imitate it.